# Query collection by 2 parameters inside doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
//Count y Maxcount are inside a doc of the collection door.
db.collection("door").where("count","<","maxcount")

//Like this
Door -> someID -> count: 9 maxcount: 10
```

I need to bring the door that have not reach his max count . 
Each door has a different maxcount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in a condition needs to be a literal value, it cannot be a reference to another field.

The common solution would be to add an addition field that contains the difference between `count` and `maxcount`, for example `count_delta` and then filter on that field: `db.collection("door").where("count_delta",">", 0)`.